# Renaming the "Order of the Sticks" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Just tried to fix the tag name on Pureferret's question, [Is Vaarsuvius male or female?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/is-vaarsuvius-male-or-female), since the name of the webcomic is singular ([Order of the Stick](http://www.giantitp.com/Comics.html)) and got an error message about "order-of-the-sticks" already existing:

`Creating the new tag [order-of-the-stick] is not allowed since the tag [order-of-the-sticks] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.`

Can it be renamed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops. Sticks? What sticks? It says [order-of-the-stick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-of-the-stick). It has always said [order-of-the-stick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-of-the-stick). We have always been at war with Azure City. Move along.